# No one can login and access denied message

Tags: 7, users, sessions

The site worked till yesterday and just now it's behaving strangely.

- <del>The site is **not** created with features, an archive dump including the code and database is copied to server, and the old installation is replaced with the new one manually (unfortunately).</del> Now it is irrelavant  also happening on local server.
- No caching module is installed. Session API is not also installed.
- Theme is set to 'seven' (core admin theme, just in case).
- The watchdog does not contain any error, warning or info except the usual "session opened for user xyz";
- The settings file does not contain any special cookie directive. It never did.
- The site is running on php 5.6, Apache 2.2, CentOS 6. PHP is running as fast-cgi. Same as always.
- It's Drupal 7.

I go to example.com/user/login, enter username and password, the form is submitted successfully, the page is redirected to example.com/user/%uid (tried both uid 1 and other users). and boom! I get an *access denied*. And the user is not logged in.

If I truncate the **sessions** table with `truncate table sessions` I can log in once and once only, with any user. Then again no one can log-in not even uid 1.

Also with a password reset link (using the command `drush uli` I can log in with no problem).

I disabled *all* contrib modules and theme, but the same problem persists.

What is causing such problems with sessions? any ideas?

Comment: If this is Drupal 6 make sure the anonymous user record in the database still has a `uid` of 0 (it often gets nuked by sql dumping software and re-numbered). What you're describing is exactly what happens when that record goes awol

Comment: @Clive thanks, I checked but uid 0 is there. Importing the same DB dump on my laptop works fine also. and it's D7, I edited the question.

Comment: I am guessing this has to do with the hashing of the passwords.Maybe you should force your users to reregister and redo their password. On the new domain the password hash will be changed and therefor will never be valid...

Comment: @Akko nope... still I get an access denied. 
I do get a wrong password error if a wrong password is entered, but the problem is the mysterious access denied.

Comment: @loolooyyyy Did you install 'content access' module or something like?

Comment: Is there a canonical url set in settings.php? I had a similar error for a page when users tried to log in using `example.com/user` but where redirected to `www.example.com/user/1`.

Comment: @KrishnaMohan thanks, but no. Even if it was installed, I don't think it would be the case? upon logging in, there wont be any node access checks. user is simply redirected to their profile page.

Comment: @Paul thanks but no, it's just a plain settings.php file! I haven't changed a line of it.

Comment: Well, if you use the one-time login provided by `drush uli`, the system requires you to set a new password (afaik). I assume you did that? If you then logout and login again with the new password, this still happens? Is there any error message in your server log (by default to be found in sth like `/var/log/apache2/error_log`)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem was [ip_geoloc](https://drupal.org/project/ip_geoloc) module. It was messing up $_SESSION variable, a solution is given on [the issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2366249) (for now!) and the module author agrees with it. It's highly probable that it is happening because of a mis-configuration by me. The user was successfully logged in but immediately their session was invalidated. Somehow disabling it was not enough and it's directory had to be moved out of Drupal root. I am 100% sure not any of it's functions or APIs are used anywhere else. Maybe some cache problem?

#### Lesson learned:

When having signing-in problem, try to check the $_SESSION variable **on the server** using [devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel) and it's helper functions (e.g [dpm](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7), [dsm](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dsm/7), [dd](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dd/7), ... or as a last resort var_export) and not with you google/firefox developers console.

This is the third time I'm facing this strange behavior and the first time I was able to fix. If you are having this problem, try to follow this checklist:

#### Ask yourself:

- Does truncating the *sessions* table fix the problem?
- Does *forcing a change for user password* fix the problem?
- Have you added any particular configuration to your *settings.php*? e.g base_url, cookie_domain, ...
- Does *UID 0* exist in your database (i.e anonymous user)?
- Is any *redirection* module installed? [search404](https://drupal.org/project/search404), [redirect](https://drupal.org/project/redirect), [global_redirect](https://drupal.org/project/global_redirect),...
- Do you have a *custom module* enabled?
- Is there any problems with your *theme*?
- Do you have any path altering modules, e.g path_alias?
- Do you have any module changing the log-in behavior? e.g [logintoboggan](https://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan)
- Have you enabled any caching module? e.g [authcache](https://drupal.org/project/authcache), [memcache](https://drupal.org/project/memcache), [session_cache](https://drupal.org/project/session_cache), [boost](https://drupal.org/project/boost), [varnish](https://drupal.org/project/varnish), ...
- Do you have any access control module enabled? e.g workbench, content_access, acl, og_access, ...
- And finally, have you enabled any module which changes the user $_SESSION? e.g [session_api](https://drupal.org/project/session_api), [session_cache](https://drupal.org/project/session_cache), [ip_geoloc](https://drupal.org/project/ip_geoloc), ...

#### Places to look / Things to do

- Look at drupals watchdog messages. If you can not log-in, use drush watchdog-show --tail to see what's happening.
- If running apache and mod-php, look in apache's error log, usually at /var/log/apache/error_log for *nix systems.
- If running php-fpm, see the php-fpm log, make sure there is no communication problem with php daemon, such as headers are not lost. if you see no error log try running your site with drush/php internal server. the command is `drush rs` or `drush rs the.ip.goes.here:thePort`
- make a fullbackup, disable all modules with this command AFTER making a full backup (you can make a backup with `drush ard` or just database `drush sql-dump > db.sql` or use backup_migrate module)
  `drush dis -y $(drush pml --no-core --status=enabled --pipe)` -> this command only works in *nix systems I don't know the direct translation for windows.
- Set your default theme to something... safe! such as seven or garland. If you can not log-in use this drush commands:
  `drush en seven && drush vset theme_default seven`;
- Monitor $_SESSION variable with any debugging tool, see if it's content are correct, ok, healthy.
- For all the processes and daemons involved in serving a request (nginx, php-fpm, apache, varnish...) make sure they all have write access to their tmp directory.

Good luck debugging!

Comment: When it happened to me, it turned out to be a problem with a client side, namely the cookie stored in the browser I was using. So, clearing (deleting) the local cookie for the website in the browser solved the problem. A convenient way to test it is to login the website with a newly launched browser in the *incognito or private* mode.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was enabling and configuring the `$cookie_domain` variable in settings.php (because I have a site that can be accessed by 2 different domains).

Pay attention to the comment before this variable! The domain name must start with a period. EX:

`$cookie_domain = '.example.com';`

Good luck!

Comment: You saved me hours of debugging