# `drush uli` generates correct link but results in 'Access Denied'

Tags: 7, drush

I have set up a *Drush* alias for my website (hosted on a shared hosting), the alias works correctly, because commands like `drush status`, `drush cc all`, etc. work. The problem comes with `drush uli`. It generates the one-time login link, the domain is correct, everything looks all right, but when entered into a browser, it results in *standard* Drupal

> Access Denied

page.

*Part of setting up the alias and some interesting issues around `path-alias`-es, relations to database settings, it's usage and relevancy the aliases is originally discussed in [Drush issues page on GitHub](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/831).*

Technical information:

- This is a clean Drupal 7 installation, without contrib modules.
- I can log in using password (even using password set via `drush upwd` using the same alias).
- I have checked all possible sources (like truncating `sessions` table, etc.) discussed in [similar but yet different issue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/131637/no-one-can-login-and-access-denied-message) on StackExchange.
- I have tried different browsers and cleared browser caches and cookies as suggested in various similar discussions on Drupal.org, all without luck.

---

Drush alias:

```
$aliases['myalias'] = array(
  'uri' => 'mysite.com',
  'root' => '/home/mysite.com/web',
  'path-aliases' => array(
    '%drush' => '/home/.composer/vendor/drush/drush',
   ),
  '%files' => '/home/mysite.com/web/sites/mysite.com/files',
);
```

The alias works correctly for other commands like clearing caches and `drush status` confirms that Drupal is bootstrapped correctly.

Comment: are you using uri parameter ?

Comment: @DavidLukac On which URI you have `Access Denied`? Does it recognise the token and redirects first?

Comment: @HimanshuPathak The URI is directly in the alias.

Comment: @kenorb The `Access Denied` is directly on the token URL.  The `watchdog` says: `415` | `0` | `access denied` | `user/reset/1/1445605040/kxvcztB8oYE5PdRDS02j_Gsef_5eI1gcSvzuSenzotE/login` | ...  `http://example.com/user/reset/1/1445605040/kxvcztB8oYE5PdRDS02j_Gsef_5eI1gcSvzuSenzotE/login` so the location and URI and URL all seem to be correct.

Comment: @DavidLukac Do you have Access Denied when you're using invalid token? I've tested [this link](http://davidlukac.com//user/reset/1/1446211356/KwZQ4gdpqfek9Zwg-fZIquWh-hAfnFGPVP7fS-bFGQc/login) and it gets redirected (so it recognised that the token is not right) and it's showing the message `You have tried to use a one-time login ...`, so at least not Access Denied.

Comment: I deleted the password in the database and the `uli` works :-o :facepalm: Thanks for the help and time guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why the `drush uli` gets to *Access Denied*. I suspect it's something with validation/generation of the one time links and/or incorrect timestamp in the *users* table.

The solution was deleting the password in the database. (Changing it via `drush upwd` or directly in Drupal didn't work.) After deleting the user's password I was able to run `drush uli`.

Comment: when you say 'delete password' do you mean delete values in users.pass?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Per [this comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/179259/drush-uli-generates-correct-link-but-results-in-access-denied#comment216277_179259), yes.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that "I deleted the password in the database" == "delete values in users.pass field"

Comment: `drush upwd` worked for me!

Comment: Beware... as I mentioned [above](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/179259/drush-uli-generates-correct-link-but-results-in-access-denied#comment305351_213691), user 1 is an account you should be protecting carefully. Of course if it's your development site on a local machine, go ahead by all means.

Answer (score 16):

This can happen when the user is blocked. Setting the status to 1 in the Users table may resolve it.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. One would think drush does that validation first

Comment: Beware. The command `drush uli` logs you in as user 1 by default. User 1 is often blocked for a reason: it can bypass any access checks, so the account is a potential security risk (especially as its username is often the same across sites, "admin").

The solution is to set up a different user account with as many administrator permissions as you need, which you could do once via user 1 (then block it).

Use `drush uli UID`, `drush uli 'username'` or `drush uli email@example.com` to log in as that user.

Comment: Unblock the user via drush:
drush user:unblock admin

Comment: Print user information using drush:
drush user-information 1

Answer (score 5):

Just ran across this in a local dev setup.. turned out to be the `$cookie_domain` setting that was committed in `settings.php`... if this is set to the production URL, you will *not* get a valid cookie, and therefore access will never be granted. Overriding `$cookie_domain` to match the local dev environment in `local-settings.php` did the trick!

Answer (score 3):

Also check the [flood table](https://www.drupal.org/node/1023440). Its possible there are records that are failed attempts by IP address that are blocking access.